# Error trying deserialize a json to C# class with byte[]

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, serialization, deserialization

I am working on 2 projects, one is mobile app in c# xamarin, the other is desktop software c# windows form.

I am using Newtonsoft Json nugget package to serializer / deserializer data (in my c# mobile app and desktop software) and a WebService in PHP to "link" the software and the app (large amount of data).

It's working great for most of the classes, but, for one class, I have 4 byte[] attributs to store images (and a bunch of other attributs , in string, decimal etc).

When my JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is used on my class with some byte[], I got the error

"Invalid length for a Base64 char array or string when deserializing"

Serializing on my mobile app

```
//listeDocuments is a List<document>, document class is the one with byte[]
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listeDocuments);
```

Deserializing on windows software

```
listeDocuments.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<document>>(JSON));
```

Working great when the byte[] = null

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: is the image data base64 encoded?

Comment: Normally yes, but I will try to add

```
 string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureClient);
                signatureClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64);
```

At the end

Comment: have you verified that the data is being encoded correctly in the json? Are you sure that the data is not being corrupted when transmitted to the PHP site?

Comment: For this yes I am pretty sure, the nugget package create the json, it's sended to a DB without any action possible, and it's coming back on the other program from the DB.

But encoding tje image data to base64 is the solution I think. I just have another issue to validate, I need now to set the byte[] to original value to display it. What is the default type ? I am converting byte [] ??? to base64 byte[], now I need to do base64 byte[] to byte[] ???

Thanks

Comment: I asked if your data was encoded and you said "yes".  If it is NOT encoded, then you need to figure out why the deserializer thinks it is.  The first thing I would suggest is verifying that the data is being transmitted from mobile --> PHP --> windows without any errors.

Comment: The data is correclty encoded, yes.

And I manage to make it working ! The image data was not base 64 encoded, that was the issue.

So, I encode it to base 64, so I can deserialize without any issue. And use 

 byte[] decodedByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(base64byte[]));

If I want to display it, perfect !

Thanks for your help :)